# Why is Sooryavansham overly broadcast on Set Max / Sony Max?

Tags: distribution, sooryavansham

*Sooryavansham* is quite a popular Bollywood film, but it got more of a cult role due to repeated telecast on Set Max (now known as Sony Max). It is even part of many memes/jokes:

[image][image]

But why is the channel broadcasting this single movie so many times? It seems like it's playing daily or even several times a day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edited the below answer because I found a more credible source from [mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mint_(newspaper)), one of the more credible business news media*

Because it is still popular with the viewers. I found one source quoting the BARC (Broadcast Audience Research Council) stats [here](http://www.indiantelevision.com/television/tv-channels/viewership/star-max-returns-to-top-10-channels-in-across-genre-list-180202)

> Sony Max was ranked fourth in week 4 of 2018 with 639.675 million
> weekly impressions. The channel also topped BARC’s top five Hindi
> Movies channels weekly list in HSM (U+R) and HSM (U). The sequel of SS
> Rajamouli’s magnum opus – Bahubali 2: The Conclusion was among the
> five most watched movies in HSM (U+R), HSM (U) and HSM (R). **Hindi
> feature film (HFF) Sooryavansham, that was aired on the channel in
> week 4 was amongst the five most watched programmes in HSM (U+R) and
> HSM (U).** Another HFF that was aired on the channel, Bhairava, was also
> among the top-five Hindi movies in HSM (U).

HSM - Hindi Speaking Market. U - Urban. R - Rural.

From [another source](https://www.livemint.com/Consumer/VQTMjDaiZdK3LSe1FzODuJ/Why-is-1999-movie-Sooryavansham-Sony-Maxs-favourite-offer.html) confirming the same results

> Baahubali that premiered in October last year and Golmaal that was
> aired in February this year, both had one common name that **made it to
> the BARC list of top five films that week—Amitabh Bachchan’s 1999
> drama Sooryavansham.**
>
> **A remake of Tamil film Suryavamsam (1997), the E.V.V. Satyanarayana
> directed film notched up 4.4 million BARC impressions on Sony Max**
> compared to Baahubali’s 26 million on the same channel and 4.7 million
> impressions compared to Golmaal Again’s 16 million on Star Gold.
> Impressions refer to the number of individuals (in thousands) of a
> target audience who viewed an event, averaged across minutes.

Sony has bought the movie rights for 100 years according to [this](https://www.indiatvnews.com/entertainment/bollywood-sooryavansham-amitabh-bachchan-turns-18-years-382463) source.

It has reached a cult status among Indian audiences. According to Neeraj Vyas, senior vice-president and business head, Sony Max cluster, Sony Pictures Network

> "Television viewing essentially is community viewing. **Television, is
> a representation of the average Indian, the mass consumer who enjoys
> stereotypical scenes, situations and songs** and comes back to them
> whenever he can. A family entertainer like **Sooryavansham will always
> work on television because it not just allows for emotional peaks and
> curves every couple of minutes but can be watched in segments or its
> entirety** with at least one other member of the family multiple times
> without discomfort."

So as long as viewers are willing to see it, Sony Max will broadcast it.

Dread it. Run from it maybe. But Sooryavansham still arrives on Sony Max.